# Log all queries executed on SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: database, logging, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, been a technical manager I would like to monitor all the queries executed on the SQL Server Management Studio query window, is there an option to log this or any open source software I can use, kindly suggest

Comment: Why SSMS only? What about SQL Operations studio? Or the VS Code extensions? What is your *actual* requirement? You can *audit* query execution just fine with SQL Server without extra software but you have to know what you want to audit first. SQL Server's documentation already explains how to set up auditing or use Extended Events to capture queries and filter them by client application.

Comment: The answers will be different if eg you want to audit dba access to a production server (that's what [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) is for) vs finding out who run ad-hoc DDL in a development database. In this case you probably need a *change tracking* solution, not auditing

Comment: My requirement is that I have a production server where the data is generated and updated by a web application I built. But unfortunately due to certain reasons few users have access to the DB server where they update the data manually by-passing the validations, these systems are in very different geographic locations and therefore I need an option to track such updating in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Use **SQL Profiler** and insert the values into a table. Its risky as the table size will increase drastically. Also this will impact the performance of the server as well. You can filter the **resultset** based on the `ApplicationName` as `Micorsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query` and filter the events only for `T-SQL SQL:StmtStarting`